# Date Predicate for CoreData to compare Time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity named `ReservationsEntity` in CoreData. Each entry has got an attribute `reservedTime` of type `Date`.

Ex: `reservedTime` looks like `2016-05-03 23:15:00 +0000`.

Now, I have another entity named `TimeSlotsEntity` which has attributes like `timeSlotName` of type `String`, `fromTime` type `Date`, `toTime` of type `Date`.

Ex: `fromTime` looks like `2017-11-14 09:00:00 +0000` and `toTime` looks like `2017-11-14 11:59:00 +0000` .

Now, while I save each of the items to `ReservationsEntity`, I need to assign a `timeSlot` to the `reservation` item.

I am trying to write a predicate for `TimeSlotsEntity` this way:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TimeSlotsEntity> = TimeSlotsEntity.fetchRequest()

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "((fromTime <= %@) AND (toTime > %@))", reservedTime! as NSDate, reservedTime! as NSDate)



fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                if let objects = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest) {

                    print(objects)
                }
```

print statement always prints `[]`

EDIT: I only need to compare the time from `reservedTime` with that of time from `fromTime` and `toTime` of `TimeSlotsEntity`
How can I get this done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The predicate looks fine to me, are you sure reservedTime contains a valid value?

Comment: Hey! Please go through the edit. I need to only compare the times from the dates passed in the predicate.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, which is find since it was mostly rhetorical anyway. It's not much code you're showing us so it's hard to understand what could be wrong.

Comment: It's a relevant question, possibly the only one there is. The predicate is correct as written, which suggests that the problem is with `reservedTime`-- either it has a bogus value or it just doesn't match any existing time slot.